# Memory management for class member variable in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qgraphicsscene

I am writing an image viewer with Qt based on the QGraphicsScene feature of Qt. I am creating  model of each image in a class called ImageModel and manage the display of the image in a class called ImageView. The ImageView class is as follows (just the part that is interesting):

```
class ImageView
{
public:
    ImageView(QWidget *parent);

    QGraphicsView * getView() {return view; }

private:

    //qgraphics scene elements
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsView *view;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *curItem;


};
```

The constructor for the class is as follows:

```
ImageView::ImageView(QWidget *parent)
{

    //create scene and view with parent the main window
    //such that the memory management is done by qt
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(parent);
    view = new QGraphicsView(parent);

    view->setScene(scene);
}
```

Also I have pointer to an ImageView in my derivation of the QMainWindow.

My question is: should I let Qt do the memory management by seting my main window as parent of the view and the scene or should I take care of the memory management myself (leave the view and the scene without parents and delete them in the class destructors)? What is a good strategy in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the view to be nested inside the main window, then you will *have* to make it a child.

For your general question, this really comes down to your desired object lifetimes and ownership semantics.  If you don't want to the view/scene to outlive the main window then yes they should be children.  You still have the option to delete them through other means at an earlier time.

Comment: That is correct I have to make the view a child of the main window. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them anymore, do you have a reason to keep them around for the whole lifetime of the parent? If not, I don't see why you would want to keep that memory allocated.

If you don't need a resource anymore, you should free it, unless you have a reason not to. Note that you can delete them regardless of whether they have a parent or not; when you delete an object that has a parent, it removes itself from the parent's list of children.

Answer (score 0):

Let Qt take care of the deleting. Its convenient and safe. Don't keep a reference around that you don't need. For example adding a layout and keeping a reference just to delete is not worth it.